# PSX memory cards/savegames getting corrupted

Tags: final-fantasy-7, ps1, gran-turismo

My wife recently picked me up a clean, used original-design PSX (not the PSOne style, if that makes a difference) as another console for my man-cave's "retro-gaming corner".

I have been playing FFVII and Gran Turismo on it, using the same memory card for both. The card looks like the genuine Sony article, and came with the console. However, I have been having problems with the FFVII savegames becoming corrupted. I had to start over from halfway through the first disc not long ago because *both* of the savegames that I had been alternating between had become corrupted. (I now rotate between three savegames and have been saving at *every* opportunity). The GT savegames have not been corrupting, but I have a sneaking suspicion that this game could be causing the problem, as the FFVII games have always come up corrupt after switching between FFVII and GT.

Is the memory card past its prime? Should I not be trying to save both games to the same card? Is there a special arcane power-off procedure like there was when powering off the NES and SNES? Any other suggestions or additional info needed?

Comment: That's some strange symptoms.  I don't think I've ever heard of a memory card doing that.

Comment: Is it a third party memory card? I had one and was looking forward to playing some FF VII when I find out everything was gone. And I had tons of hours played. The golden chocobo etc .....

Comment: When I first read the title, my inclination was to think that the memory card is just going bad. They do that after a while.

Answer (score 2):

This post interests me as I've just started FFVII. PS One game on PS2 slim, with official PS One memory card.

The answer is to get another official PS One memory card and keep the game saves separate.
Be sure to format the card first to give it the best chance. And of course never remove it whilst saving (I am sure that you are not, but if the slots are faulty it might "wiggle" if touched and cause corruption).

You could try using memory card port two and see if it happens again.

Just to add, about third party cards, they are very different to the official ones. If you open them up the parts and design vary wildly between the official and third party ones (even from year-to-year).